# Debounce won't execute request max once per second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have the following component handling a text search. To reduce requests I'm trying to debounce my handler. My goal is to execute one request maximum every second.

The following code executes the handler on every single re-render of `value`, but with an initial delay of 1000ms. **AFAIK a debounce means that for f.i. `hello`, the request won't be executed for every single character, but max once per second, right?**

What am I doing wrong?

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");

useEffect(() => {
    handleQuery();
}, [value]);

const handleQuery = debounce(() => {
    console.log(value);
}, 1000);

return (
    <SearchWrapper>
        <SearchBar value={value} onInput={setValue} />
    </SearchWrapper>
);
```

Comment: Why don't you directly call `handleQuery` in your text input?

Comment: @RyanLe I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but because I need to update value without any delay to set the respective's input value

Comment: I see, try my answer if it works for you. using `useEffect` in this case might lead to some asynchronous action.

Comment: _the request won't be executed for every single character, but max once per second, right_.    

debounce - wait till user stops typing for X seconds and then send the request.
throttle - only execute request every X seconds.

Usually it's best to use debounce for search, so that you only get one request. Just to clarify, that is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **You don't actually need a useEffect before debouncing an action:**

**Try to change to something like this:**

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");

const handleQuery = debounce((searchText) => {
  console.log(searchText);
}, 1000);

return (
  <SearchWrapper>
    <SearchBar
      value={value}
      onInput={(searchText) => {
        setValue(searchText);
        handleQuery(searchText);
      }}
    />
  </SearchWrapper>
);
```

Comment: Thank you! You led me in the right direction - I actually additionally need to wrap the debounce function with a `useCallback` hook to make it work - I assume the re-renders caused by `value` brought up some disparities: `const debouncedFunc = useCallback(debounce(handleQuery, 1000), [])`